# PHP: How to add a logo with url link on a web player?

Tags: php, flash

I am doing a project in PHP in which Users can upload videos to the website.Visitors can watch the videos in the website. There will be a logo on the web player.when the visitor clicks on the logo it has to take him to a new page.I don't know how to add a logo with URL link on a web player. Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you have the source code for the player? which player is this? (some players can be customized to add logos)

if you answered no to both questions, you will have to use css and absolute positioning but I don't think it'll work with ie6 though

Comment: Yes I have the source code for the player. I am using JWPlayer.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.clipul.com/play/swfobject.js"></script>
<div id="player">This text will be replaced</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var so = new SWFObject('http://montsmile.com/jwplayer/player.swf','mpl','480','380','8');
so.addParam('allowscriptaccess','always');
so.addParam('allowfullscreen','true');
so.addVariable('height','310');
so.addVariable('width','470');
so.addVariable('file','http://localhost:81/newtip/<?=$videopath1?>');
so.addVariable('logo','http://localhost:81/newtip/ffmpeg/logo2.jpg');
so.addVariable("ClickURL", "http://www.google.com");

Comment: so.addVariable('captions','/upload/corrie.xml');
so.addVariable('link','<?=$full_url.'tip.php?vid='.$row_video['vid']?>');
so.addVariable('linkfromdisplay','true');
so.addVariable('linktarget','_blank');
so.addVariable('searchbar','false');
so.addVariable('skin','http://montsmile.com/jwplayer/player.swf');
so.write('player');
</script>

Comment: i mean do you have the .fla file? if you don't you do have to use css